# MVC validationSummary is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am having a weird issue in MVC.
I am using ASP.Net MVC, I have created a Partial View, which posts user's Review details to DB.
I have used `"jquery.validate.min.js"` and `"jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"` for validation purpose, on clicking Submit button, my text boxes get outline and filled with red color indicating that I have not provided mandatory values, but my validation summary is displayed blank, I have used this statement
  `<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>`, providing false value to validationsummary is also not working,
Also this page is getting binded to a IPagedList as I am also displaying a grid having paging, but i guess that is not the issue. I am just not able to figure out why my validation Summary does not display any messages even when my text boxes are getting outlined with red color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved, I did not notice that by mistake I had put the validation summary outside my Form tag, now its working fine.

Comment: Feel free to mark your solution as the accepted answer, for the benefit of future visitors.